# Downloading and using SQLite database?

Tags: database, ios, sqlite

Iam currently working on a project where i need to handle alot of data around 100mb on a iOS device. The data is currently in xml but thinking about parsing into a SQLite database.
Therefore my question is if anyone have any experience in downloading a compressed SQLite database from a webserver, uncompress the database and then search the database for content?

Comment: I'm actually working on this right now. It seems very doable. I'm just working around an old sync where every single row was put into to database from a plist downloaded from the server (became really really slow when rows hit a few thousand).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have downloaded a compressed sqllite database from a webserver, uncompressed the database and then searched the database for content.

I've also added information to the database.

Sqllite is an acceptable database, as long as you don't have a lot of concurrent writes.