# Connecting to a Remote SQLite Database on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have the SQLite Database I want to use hosted on my website already (for a web version of the app I want to make). I was wondering if there would be any way to connect to this from my iOS app to query it that way (or at the very least, download it). Is this possible at all?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "remote SQLite database" (there may be proxies, but nothing direct). Generally, one would create a [remote] Web Service (e.g. REST) to expose the required functionality - but not the database access directly. If the SQLite database is downloaded [locally], then it's just like a normal [local] SQLite database :D

Comment: Anyway, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132684/ios-download-sqlite-database-and-replace-existing-one , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518704/download-and-use-sqlite-file-in-ios , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379594/downloading-and-using-sqlite-database - found via "ios download sqlite". YMMV.

Comment: I deleted my original comment as your changed initial response is much more clear. I'm going to have it download the SQLite database from my website and use it locally. Thanks.